# React with MVC data annotations and unobtrusive validation

Tags: html, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

We are currently looking to experiment with modern frontend frameworks like react on an MVC4 project. We use data annotations in our models and we have a lot of forms that use unobtrusive validation on the UI.

The main thing is finding a way to use react to generate the content while still being able to make use of features like unobtrusive validation. As I understand it, it really is just a bunch of `data-val` attributes dynamically generated when using HTML helpers like `TextAreaFor`, `ValidationMessageFor` with the attributes getting values from the data annotations in the model classes.

I've tried several things including

```
 ReactDOM.render(
 @using (Html.BeginForm("xyz", "xyz", FormMethod.Post))
 {
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
```

which results in the input box not being editable for some reason.

I'd prefer to do something more like

```
 ReactDOM.render(
      <form><input type="text" data-val="@Model.datannotations[1].val" /></form>
```

Is that possible? How does one get the `data-val` values from the model anyway? What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: From what I can tell these .net features spit out html using controls, that doesn't work well with React as React uses a virtual DOM to keep track of it's state, that doesn't work with markup that's generated by server side frameworks.  This is very different from say jQuery where it is common to render the initial DOM via static html or server side languages, then pick up with jQuery from there.  While I love React, I don't think it is a particularly good candidate for this type of application.  It works best when used to build an independent client stack that communicates with APIs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with React, but are you using ReactJS.Net?  If not, I would suggest starting there.  You definitely want something that bridges your model data from the M in C# MVC to the V in React.  Back end validation is always important, right? So you still need data annotations in your models.  And you also don't want to duplicate work from your model to your view manually, so I'm dubious about `data-val="@Model.data...`.  That stuff should be generated dynamically.

Comment: Personally, I use rich EditorFor templates that package up the label, validation and control elements all-in-one.  That helps provide a consistent feel for my form elements across an entire application, and makes view-maintenance very simple.

Comment: You can't have 2 masters for the same DOM. You probably can shoe horn one into another but you'll save yourself a lot of trouble by simply choosing one over the other - and I'd suggest to choose React. Unobtrusive validation is a pain in itself. With react, you've many react form solution that can take care of validations in much more friction-less way.

Comment: The general design pattern for a react app is that react is loaded on a static page, and makes calls to an api to load data. So your front end and back end ideally are completely separate. (Front end handles displaying the data and reacting to user inputs, backend decides what to do with the data, but doesn't know anything about presentation logic.) This is a different design style than most MVC apps, where the backend handles some view concerns as well as data concerns. There are ways to bridge this gap, but realize that it is a different way of thinking than you may be used to...

Comment: This behavior should be controlled in the <Form>, you get the `data-` attr from server and bind it dynamically to the <Input>

Comment: You can use Attributes and remove the razor syntax. Check out this blog post. https://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2018/08/13/lean-asp-net-core-2-1-react-forms-validation-and-web-api-integration/

Comment: I forgot to note it's using typescript.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

it should not be possible.

These are two differents ways to delvelop the ui.
The razor way is preprocessing the markup code in server side to fill it.

And react works in another flow using the lifecycle methods, you should have already loaded the data-anotations values for accessing it on render.

Therefore, to make this works you have to run razor engine first to fill the markup and  next using react engine. 
I don't recommend use this approach because it's too hard to develop on it and the developers team have to keep that flow in mind while they are developing

Note this

```js
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentMustHaveJSX/>)
```